# Get total views of all posts by author

Tags: count, views, statistics

I would like to display the total amount of views per author for all posts. What would be the best way to achieve this without causing too much load on the server?

Answer (score 2):

Gathering page view statistics is inherently write operation, which is inherently heavy on resources. There are no appropriate mechanisms in WP for high volume writes at low resource consumption.

Your best bet is using external analytics system/service and retrieving page view data from it.

Comment: I've found this tutorial for adding post views per author with Analytics: [http://www.geekwire.com/devblog/add-wordpress-author-tracking-google-analytics-using-custom-dimensions/] , but it states that **Google Analytics limits you to just 20 total custom dimensions per property** - so basically 20 authors, which won't work in my case:( I guess it's simply not possible then?